# cookies are not working in chrome

Tags: javascript

This works fine in IE, but fails in chrome.

The alert box pops up but it does not display the three cookies as name/value pairs.

Cookies are enabled in chrome, if that's the issue.

```js
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path) {
  value = escape(value);
  if (!expires) {
    var now = new Date();
    now.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 6);
    expires = now.toUTCString();
  }
  if (path) {
    path = ";path =" + path;
  }
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";expires=" + expires + path;
}
setCookie("Name", "Bob");
setCookie("Age", "101");
setCookie("FirstVisit", "10 May 2017");
alert(document.cookie);
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? What error are you seeing

Comment: Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Why would having a look at that questionable resource help with the problem at hand?

Comment: The alert box pops up but it does not display the three cookies as name/value pairs.

Comment: Please tell us if you are opining the file from a server or from your local hard drive

Comment: my local hard drive